# Relationship between part dimensions and performance of ion electrospray thruster

Tags: propulsion, ion-thruster, thrust, specific-impulse, electric-propulsion

I got the relationship between power, thrust and specific impulse for an ion electrospray thruster as follows:

$$P/T= 1/2 \times g_o \times I_{\mathrm{sp}}$$

Where: $P$ = power required (in Watts), $T$ = thrust (in Newtons), $g_o$ = gravitational parameter (9.81 m/s²), $I_{\mathrm{sp}}$ = specific impulse (in seconds).

But I want to know how the dimensions of the emitter, propellant tank, extractor thickness, extractor - emitter gap, etc. affect the thrust or specific impulse of an electrospray thruster which can be used for CubeSats.

Comment: See Goebel / Katz [Fundamentals of Electric Propulsion: Ion and Hall Thrusters](http://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/SciTechBook/series1/Goebel__cmprsd_opt.pdf) (PDF), [chapter 2.2 Force Transfer in Ion and Hall Thrusters](http://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/SciTechBook/series1/Goebel_02_Chap2_thruster.pdf) (smaller, chapter 2 only PDF). Links to other chapters are listed on [DESCANSO - JPL Space Science & Technology Book Series](http://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/SciTechBook/st_series1_chapter.html).